# Android onTouchListener stops after certian code is executed from a handler

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

hope you'll bare with this piece of text I'm about to write.
So, my onTouchListener should allow movement of a view after a long press.

I initially made it so that the view removes itself from its container on event.ACTION_DOWN, and attaches itself to a FrameLayout that contains all other such subviews and their containers, and then move its margins accordingly in ACTION_MOVE events.

This worked like a charm, but I needed to allow this behaviour only after a long press so I did this:

```
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                        mainFrame.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                        h=new Handler();
                      viewCopy=view;
                        eventCopy=event;
                        h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                               enableMoving();
                            }
                        }, 3000);



                break;
```

Among other things, this function "enable moving" changes a volatile boolean into true, which is checked in the ACTION_MOVE event:

```
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                System.out.println("move event!");
                if(!isMoving) break;
                System.out.println("allowing movement!");
                //rest of code..
```

The problem is, the same function, if called directly from the ACTION_DOWN event, does this and the events keep going normally, while when called from the handler, the touch events stop (I get ACTION_CANCEL callback..).
I've narrowed down the exact lines of code which do that, namely the ones that remove the view from its container and add it again:

```
        container.removeView(viewCopy);
       viewCopy.setLayoutParams(frameParams);
       mainFrame.addView(viewCopy);
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. Sir leo, from your code anytime ACTION_DOWN gets called you create `h=new Handler();` which executes 3 seconds later, suppose i tap on the view twice in less than a second i have 2 Handlers which will execute 3secs in succession. if this should happen you only have a reference to the second handler and from your *limited info you gave*

> Among other things, this function "enable moving" changes a volatile boolean into true, which is checked in the ACTION_MOVE event:

I hope you have seen a flaw/bug in your code ?

Comment: Nah I'm canceling the handler in my ACTION_UP.

Answer (score 0):

Well if anyone attempts something like this in the future, it seems that moving the view who's touch event we're listening to to another parent in any piece of code except within the listener's onTouch method triggers an ACTION_CANCEL event.